# PrintScreenをフックしているプロセスをしりたい

Tags: windows

質問させていただきます。

Windows10でデフォルトでは

- PrintScreenキーだけを押すと画面全体をキャプチャ
- Alt+PrintScreenでアクティブなウィンドウをキャプチャ

となるかと思います。
これが今自分の環境では、どちらの操作でもアクティブなウィンドウのキャプチャとなってしまいました。
なにかのツールをインストールした拍子にそうなったのだと思うのですが、いつからこうなっているのかもわからず、判然としません。

デフォルト設定に戻す方法がありましたらご教示お願いします。

Comment: 長い記事なので紹介だけ。ここ[How do I find out which programs have registered global hotkeys in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1091942)で調査方法の質問が解決済みで詳細な解説もあるようです。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。解決しました。